# Ford F-150 4x2 4.9l straight 6 misses after lots of work

Tags: engine, ford, rough-idle, f-150

Just seems like plug wire, plug, or something missing shakes whole truck. It's acting like it's starving for gas. New plugs, plug wires, MAF sensor, idle control sensor, cleaned and still can't figure out why it's missing or losing power.

I know nothing about a Ford truck. Crank it, sounds like a little miss. Rev it up, starts missing terrible. Start to drive, it's boggy slow till 20-30, then starts to run good, then bogs down actng like it's gonna cut off, popping and sputtering. Can't figure anything out.

Comment: are the plugs gapped correctly? plug wires connected to the correct cylinders?

Comment: Pull one plug wire at a time, put each one back before trying another. If it runs the same or runs better, you have identified a problem.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad - no updates/answers from OP